# Spring : BeanCreationException : Error creating bean with name

Tags: java, spring, maven, jetty

```
    2013-11-01 08:39:14,074 ERROR org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'viewSecurityAdvisor' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/wisemapping-security.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'viewSecurityAdvice' while setting bean property 'advice'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'viewSecurityAdvice' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/wisemapping-security.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'mindmapService' while setting bean property 'mindmapService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mindmapService' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/wisemapping-service.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'mindMapServiceTarget' while setting bean property 'target'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mindMapServiceTarget' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/wisemapping-service.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'mindmapManager' while setting bean property 'mindmapManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mindmapManager' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/wisemapping-model.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'hibernateTemplate' while setting bean property 'hibernateTemplate'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hibernateTemplate' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/wisemapping-dao.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'mindmapSessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mindmapSessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/wisemapping-dao.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'wiseDataSource' while setting bean property 'dataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'wiseDataSource': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.cloudfoundry.runtime.env.CloudServiceException: Expected 1 service of class org.cloudfoundry.runtime.env.RdbmsServiceInfo type, but found0
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:275)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:104)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1245)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1010)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:472)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:380)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:264)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:261)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:164)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:429)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:728)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:380)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:255)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:199)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:45)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:549)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:136)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1282)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:518)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:499)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.Jetty6PluginWebAppContext.doStart(Jetty6PluginWebAppContext.java:115)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.doStart(ContextHandlerCollection.java:156)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:224)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.Jetty6PluginServer.start(Jetty6PluginServer.java:132)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.AbstractJettyMojo.startJetty(AbstractJettyMojo.java:454)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.AbstractJettyMojo.execute(AbstractJettyMojo.java:396)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.Jetty6RunWar.execute(Jetty6RunWar.java:67)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd"
         version="2.4">

    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.localizationContext</param-name>
        <param-value>messages</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/wisemapping-security.xml
            /WEB-INF/wisemapping-dao.xml
            /WEB-INF/wisemapping-service.xml
            /WEB-INF/wisemapping-model.xml
            /WEB-INF/wisemapping-acegi-security.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!--
      - Loads the root application context of this web app at startup.
      - The application context is then available via
      - WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(servletContext).
    -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>com.wisemapping.service.HibernateAppListener</listener-class>
    </listener>


    <filter>
        <filter-name>charsetFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>encoding</param-name>
            <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>charsetFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>hibernate</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>singleSession</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>sessionFactoryBeanName</param-name>
            <param-value>mindmapSessionFactory</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>Acegi Filter Chain Proxy</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.acegisecurity.util.FilterToBeanProxy</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>targetClass</param-name>
            <param-value>org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>Acegi Filter Chain Proxy</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>hibernate</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>wisemapping</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>

        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>
                /WEB-INF/wisemapping-servlet.xml
                /WEB-INF/wisemapping-captcha.xml
            </param-value>
        </init-param>

    </servlet>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dwr-invoker</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.directwebremoting.servlet.DwrServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>debug</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>wisemapping</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dwr-invoker</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/dwr/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>
            index.jsp
        </welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>180</session-timeout>
    </session-config>
</web-app>
```

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <artifactId>wise-webapp</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>WiseMapping Webapp</name>
    <url>http://www.wisemapping.org</url>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.wisemapping</groupId>
        <artifactId>wisemapping</artifactId>
        <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>                                                
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <repositories>
         <repository>
          <id>maven2-repository.dev.java.net</id>
          <name>Java.net Repository for Maven</name>
          <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2/</url>
          <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>
         <repository>
          <id>maven2-repository.jahia.org</id>
          <name>Jahia Repository for Maven</name>
          <url>http://maven.jahia.org/maven2/</url>
          <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>
        <repository>
           <id>org.springframework.maven.milestone</id>
           <name>Spring Maven Milestone Repository</name>
           <url>http://maven.springframework.org/milestone</url>
           <snapshots>
                   <enabled>false</enabled>
           </snapshots>
        </repository>


    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.wisemapping</groupId>
            <artifactId>core-js</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
                <groupId>org.cloudfoundry</groupId>
                <artifactId>cloudfoundry-runtime</artifactId>
                <version>0.8.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.wisemapping</groupId>
            <artifactId>mindplot</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.velocity</groupId>
            <artifactId>velocity</artifactId>
            <version>1.5</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>5.8</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <classifier>jdk15</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.intellij</groupId>
            <artifactId>annotations</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.3</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.6</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc-struts</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.6</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts-tiles</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.8</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.6</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.6</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
            <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1B</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
      <!-- <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jhlabs</groupId>
            <artifactId>imaging</artifactId>
            <version>01012005</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency> -->
        <dependency>
             <groupId>com.octo.captcha</groupId>
             <artifactId>jcaptcha</artifactId>
             <version>1.0</version>
             <scope>compile</scope>
         </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.6</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-ws-support</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.6</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-ws-core-tiger</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.6</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.3</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.xmlgraphics</groupId>
                <artifactId>batik-codec</artifactId>
                <version>1.7</version>
                <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.directwebremoting</groupId>
            <artifactId>dwr</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.3</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.xmlgraphics</groupId>
            <artifactId>batik-svg-dom</artifactId>
            <version>1.7</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>xalan</groupId>
                    <artifactId>xalan</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.xmlgraphics</groupId>
            <artifactId>batik-transcoder</artifactId>
            <version>1.7</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>xalan</groupId>
                    <artifactId>xalan</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.acegisecurity</groupId>
            <artifactId>acegi-security</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.7</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-dao</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-support</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-remoting</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.5</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.2</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.9</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Only for test purposes -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>hsqldb</groupId>
            <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.0.10</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

<< BeanCreationException Error creating bean with name>>

1. mvn install -> wise-mapping.war is created
2. cd wise-webapp
3. mvn jetty:run-war

then.. error... I don't know why? ....please...please help me..

Answer (score 0):

The actual error is

```
nested exception is org.cloudfoundry.runtime.env.CloudServiceException: Expected 1 service of class org.cloudfoundry.runtime.env.RdbmsServiceInfo type, but found0
```

You dont have a bean of type `RdbmsServiceInfo`.

Answer (score 0):

If you declare one or more interfaces or classes in same class then this error occurred.

Comment: The error specifically states that it found 0, not one or more